# How to install djvu plugin for firefox in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: firefox-extensions, djvu

Tried installing these packages:

1. djview
2. djview-plugin
3. djvulibre-plugin

But the plugin is not working.

In Firefox Whenever I click a djvu file, Firefox asks to download that file.

How can I fix it?